# Get variable value from different function in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

sorry for being quite the noob,

I made a form with google apps script, including an upload button to upload a file. After uploading the file I want to get the hyperlink to that file and use it in a different function, where I get the values entered by the user and put in them in a google sheet.

This is the Code.gs:
After uploading it saves the obj to the drive:

```
function saveFile(obj) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(globalVariables().driveFolder).createFile(blob);
  cellFormula = 'hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '";"' + file.getName() + '")';
}
```

I'm trying to get that cellFormula value into a different function:

```
function getFormValues(formObject){
  if(formObject.RecId && checkID(formObject.RecId)){    
    var values = [[
                  formObject.RecId.toString(),
                  formObject.datum,
                  [...],
                  cellFormula
                  ]];
    
  } else{
    var values = [[
                  new Date().getTime().toString(),//https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/51012/244121
                  formObject.datum,
                  [...],
                  cellFormula
                  ]];
  }
  return values;
}
```

But this doesn't work of course. How can I get cellFormula from the first function into the other function?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: The full code (only the relevant bits):
Form.html:

```
<form id="myForm" class="p-2 border border-light rounded bg-light" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
[ ... bunch of input fields ... ]
  
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Doorvoeren</button>
      
</form>


<form id="myFormUpload" class="p-2 border border-light rounded bg-light">
         <input type="file" name="upload" id="files"/> 
         <input type='button' id="uploadButton" value='Upload' onclick='getFiles()'> 
         <br>    <div id="progress">  </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript.html:

```
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    hidenForm();
    
    // DATUM INVULLEN IN DATUM VELD
    var field = document.querySelector('#datum');
    var date = new Date();
    // Set the date
    field.value = date.getFullYear().toString() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, 0) +  '-' + date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, 0);
  }



  function getFiles() {
      document.getElementById("uploadButton").disabled = true;
      const progressText = document.getElementById("progress");
      const f = document.getElementById('files');
      var uploadCompletedCount = 0;
      progressText.innerHTML = "Uploading file " + (uploadCompletedCount + 1) + "/" + [...f.files].length + "";
      [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = (e) => {
          const data = e.target.result.split(",");
          const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
            uploadCompletedCount++;
            progressText.innerHTML = "Upload voltooid";
            if (uploadCompletedCount >= [...f.files].length){
              google.script.host.close();
            }
            else{
              progressText.innerHTML = "Bestand uploaden... " + (uploadCompletedCount + 1) + "/" + [...f.files].length + "";
            }
          }).saveFile(obj);
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        //var fotourl = fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        //return fotourl;
      });
    }
```

And Code.gs:

```
/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  if(formObject.RecId && checkID(formObject.RecId)){                       //Execute if form passes an ID and if is an existing ID
    updateData(getFormValues(formObject),globalVariables().spreadsheetId,getRangeByID(formObject.RecId)); // Update Data
  }
  else{ //Execute if form does not pass an ID
    appendData(getFormValues(formObject),globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().insertRange); //Append Form Data
  }
  return getUrenGebruiker(); 
}



function getFormValues(formObject){
  if(formObject.RecId && checkID(formObject.RecId)){    
    var values = [[
                  formObject.RecId.toString(),
                  formObject.datum,
                  [ ... more fields ...] 
                  cellFormula
                  ]];
    
  } else{
    var values = [[
                  new Date().getTime().toString(),//https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/51012/244121
                  formObject.datum,
                  [ ... more fields ...] 
                  cellFormula
                  ]];
  }
  return values;
}



function saveFile(obj) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(globalVariables().driveFolder).createFile(blob);
  cellFormula = 'hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '";"' + file.getName() + '")';
}
```

So on submitting the form it gets all the data from the input fields. The upload is a different form which I placed inside the other form. When clicking on the upload button it activates the function getFiles().

Comment: Can you share a complete code? Are you using form submit trigger? when the form was submitted. I need to know when did you call the `saveFile()` and when are you calling `getFormValues()`. Is your `formObject` and `obj` has the same content?

Comment: saveFile() comes from a different form, essentially. Maybe I have to design it differently, but if this is possible I'd like to do it this way. 

EDIT: I'll edit the original post to include the full code.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I pretty much got the gist about your code. But I did not see where you plan to call `getFormValues()`

Comment: Since I don't know how you call `getFormValues()` (not sure if it is in your javascript html or in apps script). You might want to return the `cellFormula` in your `saveFile()` then save that in a global variable in your javascript html (assuming you plan to call getFormValues() in your html code)

Comment: Sorry about that. I included it in the code in the 1st post. It's this bit, in the Code.gs:


`function processForm(formObject){  
  if(formObject.RecId && checkID(formObject.RecId)){        
    updateData(getFormValues(formObject),globalVariables().spreadsheetId,getRangeByID(formObject.RecId)); // Update Data
  }
  else{ //Execute if form does not pass an ID
    appendData(getFormValues(formObject),globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().insertRange); //Append Form Data
  }
  return getUrenGebruiker(); 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option where you can use [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to save your cell formula string in apps script.

### Sample Code:

```
function saveFile(obj) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(globalVariables().driveFolder).createFile(blob);
  cellFormula = 'hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '";"' + file.getName() + '")';

  var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var formulaStr = scriptProp.getProperty('formula');
  Logger.log(formulaStr);
  if(formulaStr){
    formulaStr = formulaStr +','+cellFormula;
    Logger.log(formulaStr);
    scriptProp.setProperty('formula',formulaStr);
  }
  else{
    //save initial data to script properties
    scriptProp.setProperty('formula',cellFormula);
    Logger.log("Saved")
  }
}

function getFormValues(formObject){
  //get saved formula
  var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var formulaStr = scriptProp.getProperty('formula');
  var cellFormula = [];

  Logger.log(formulaStr);
  Logger.log(cellFormula);
  if(formulaStr){
    cellFormula = formulaStr.split(',');
  }
  Logger.log(cellFormula);
  //Reset script property
  scriptProp.deleteProperty('formula');

  //Do your original processing here
}
```

### Note:

- I noticed in your code that it might be possible to upload multiple files in your form. Hence this sample code can handle/save multiple `cellFormula` per files being uploaded in your form.
- I based the solution in the assumption that you upload the file first before clicking the submit button of the form.
- You can removed the logs I used for debugging.

### What it does?

1. When you upload file/files using the upload button, each file will have its own `cellFormula`. In `saveFile()`, get the script properties with property key `formula`. If it doesn't exist yet, create the property key and set its value based on the `cellFormula` string. If the key already exist, append the current `cellFormula` string with a `comma`.
2. When you submit the form, get the script properties with the property key `formula`. If it exist, split the formula string using [string.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to get an array of `cellFormula` string. Then process each saved formula based on your preference
3. Keep in mind that once you processed the formula that you saved in the script properties when you submit the form, you need to delete the existing key to clear the script properties for the next form submission with file upload.

Comment: Please let me know if you have some issues regarding the proposed solution so I could update accordingly.

Comment: Oh my! I am very grateful! Thank you so much for your time and effort! It finally works! I modified it slightly, as it gave an error with the list:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.append failed with error: Invalid values[16][20]: list_value {
  values {
    string_value: "hyperlink(\"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lexc61H0ODkjyDCJtPPo-cu6kxkFXJbJ/view?usp=drivesdk\";\"IMG_8004.JPG\")"
  }
}

    at appendData(Code:179:44)
    at processForm(Code:58:5)

But it works. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that.  By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)